# I need to plot Throughtput vs Time and Rx power vs time in 2 subplots

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am using the following MATLAB code to plot the below graphs:

```
figure
a1=subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t_warp,tp_warp,'-bo','Linewidth',1);
ylim([0,30])
datetick('x',13) 
xlabel('Time [02-11-2015]  ');
ylabel('TP (54Mbps) ');
grid on; 

a2=subplot(2,1,2)
errorbar(t_warp,rx_pow_warp,rx_err_warp,'-rd','Linewidth',1);
ylim([-30,-75])
datetick('x',13) 
xlabel('Time [02-11-2015] ');
ylabel('Received power (dBm) with deviaton ');
grid on;
```

[image]

1. How can I sync the two Timestamps on X axes? In the above generated figure, the X axis time stamp is not synced between the graphs. EDIT: using `linkaxes([a1,a2],'x')`, the two timestamp synced.
2. How can I set the X axis limit for Time? I.e. 14:00:00-23:00:00 with the interval shown for each single hour.

EDIT:

```
figure

a1=subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t_warp,tp_warp,'-bo','Linewidth',1);
space = 0.05*(max(t_warp)- min(t_warp));
xlim([min(t_warp)-space, max(t_warp)+space])
set(gca,'xTick',min(t_warp):0.1:max(t_warp)) % SHOW INTERMEDIATE POINT IN X axis
set(gca,'xTickLabel',min(t_warp):0.1:max(t_warp))

ylim([0,30])
set(gca,'yTick',0:1:30)
datetick('x',13) 
xlabel('Time [02-11-2015]  ');
ylabel('TP  ');
grid on; 


a2=subplot(2,1,2)
errorbar(t_warp,rx_pow_warp,rx_err_warp,'-rd','Linewidth',1);
space = 0.05*(max(t_warp)- min(t_warp));
% xlim([min(t_warp)-space, max(t_warp)+space])
set(gca,'xTick',min(t_warp):0.1:max(t_warp)) % SHOW INTERMEDIATE POINT IN X axis
set(gca,'xTickLabel',min(t_warp):0.1:max(t_warp))
ylim([-70,-55])
set(gca,'yTick',-70:1:-55)
datetick('x',13) 
%axis tight
xlabel('Time [02-11-2015] ');
ylabel('Received power (dBm) with deviaton ');
grid on;

linkaxes([a1,a2],'x')
```

Graph obtained: [image]

Q: Still the X axis of two graph is not starting from 14:00:00? And How to fix the same margin spacing on X axis for both graph?

Comment: You can use xlim([]) as you used ylim.... something like 
`xlim([0.9* min(t_warp), 1.1* max(t_warp)]) ` in both subplots. The grid is then similar for both plots...

Comment: It works. Thanks.What is the logic behind using 0.9 and 1.1?

Comment: @horseshoe since the OP mentions your comment as working, please consider making it an answer. This has the benefit of you gaining some reputation and SO having an unanswered question less.

Answer (score 1):

Related to the comments I made earlier you might want to use `xlim` as

```
xlim([min(t_warp), max(t_warp)])
```

if you would like the data not to start directly on the axis and have some space in between you can do it in the following way...

```
[floor(min(...)) ceil(max(...))]
```

or ...

```
relspace = 0.05;
absspace = relspace*(max(t_warp)- min(t_warp));
xlim([min(t_warp)-absspace , max(t_warp)+absspace])
```

where `relspace` sets the distance from the axis using your data range.

Comment: Using your approach I re plotted the graph but which i have attached in EDIT section.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted the above example
you can get the tixks from your first graph using

```
ticks = (get(gca,'Xtick'));
```

and then you can insert them in the second graph

```
set(gca,'Xtick',ticks)
```

that should solve it. You also might need to converte the date into a number for the `xlim`
Below a longer example...

```
close all
clear all

t = datetime('now','TimeZone','local','Format','d-MMM-y HH:mm:ss Z');
t2 = t+100;
t3 = t+300;

subplot 311
plot(t:t2,rand(size(t:t2)))
xlim([datenum(min(t)), datenum(max(t2,t3))])
ticks = (get(gca,'Xtick'));
grid on

subplot 312
plot(t:t3,rand(size(t:t3)))
grid on 

subplot 313
plot(t:t3,rand(size(t:t3)))
xlim([datenum(min(t)), datenum(max(t2,t3))])
set(gca,'Xtick',ticks)
grid on
```